# Issue when writing and reading to binary file

Tags: c

I am trying to create a synthetic dataset (values between 0-1) and save them in binary file. The following is my code:

```
int n = 4000, dim = 4,i,j;
FILE *fp=fopen("dataset.data", "w+");
double *data = (double *) calloc(n * dim, sizeof(double));
double *data_to_read = (double *) calloc(n * dim, sizeof(double));

// Generate dataset
srand(1);
for (i = 0; i < (n * dim); ++i) {
    data[i] = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
}

// Writing to binary file
if (fp) fwrite(data, 1, (n*dim) * sizeof(double), fp);
else { printf("Something went wrong while writing to File !!  \n"); }

// To make sure data have been written, read and print out the file. 
fp = fopen("Home/dataset.data", "rb");
fread(data_to_read, 1, (n*dim) * sizeof(double), fp);
fclose(fp);

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("[%d] ", i);
    for (j = 0; j < dim; ++j) {
        printf("%f, ", data_to_read[i * dim + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

However, I get a lot of zeros at the end of the printing which makes me think that there is something wrong. Something like this:

```
[3962] 0.519062, 0.877532, 0.686047, 0.396526, 
[3963] 0.419497, 0.494090, 0.163209, 0.061352, 
[3964] 0.144232, 0.113827, 0.082452, 0.777153, 
[3965] 0.609784, 0.647998, 0.902744, 0.414265, 
[3966] 0.543551, 0.462175, 0.775620, 0.842364, 
[3967] 0.607382, 0.274029, 0.599672, 0.682604, 
[3968] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3969] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3970] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3971] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3972] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3973] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3974] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3975] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3976] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3977] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3978] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3979] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3980] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3981] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3982] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3983] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3984] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3985] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3986] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3987] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3988] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3989] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3990] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3991] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3992] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3993] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3994] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3995] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3996] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3997] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3998] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
[3999] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
```

I don't know if my way of writing is correct. Any help is appriacted.

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen()` as soon as and every time you call the function. Also, you open the same file you forgot to close. You should `fclose(fp)`before `fp = fopen("Home/dataset.data", "rb");`

Comment: Also, check the return value of fwrite/fread.

Comment: @Badda You are right. The positioning of `fopen` was the problem. It is now fixed. THANK YOU

Comment: if you use binary mode (`b`) when reading, you should also use it when writing.

Comment: With code like this, you rely on the file only being read from a program with the exact same internal representation AND byte ordering of a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your code:

- You are not `fclose`ing the file once you have written to it.
- You don't check for all `fopen`s if they have succeeded.
- You need to open the file with "wb" and not "w+".
- You are not reading the same file than you write.
- If the file could not be opened for writing, you display an error message, but you still continue trying to read from the file you couldn't open

Corrected program (including correction of pointless comments and doubtful error messages), comments with `<<` are mine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int n = 4000, dim = 4, i, j;
  FILE *fp = fopen("dataset.data", "wb");                   // <<  wee need "wb" here
  double *data = calloc(n * dim, sizeof(double));          // << no casts in C
  double *data_to_read = calloc(n * dim, sizeof(double));

  // Generate dataset
  srand(1);
  for (i = 0; i < (n * dim); ++i) {
    data[i] = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
  }

  // Writing to binary file
  if (fp)
    fwrite(data, 1, (n*dim) * sizeof(double), fp);
  else 
  {
    printf("Something went wrong while opening the file to write !!  \n"); 
    return 1;                     // << abort of file could not be opened
  }

  fclose(fp);                     // << closing file

  // Read and print out the file. 
  fp = fopen("dataset.data", "rb");  // << opening the same file than the one we wrote to

  if (fp)                          // << checking if file could be opened
  {
    fread(data_to_read, 1, (n*dim) * sizeof(double), fp);
    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      printf("[%d] ", i);
      for (j = 0; j < dim; ++j) {
        printf("%f, ", data_to_read[i * dim + j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Something went wrong while opening the file to read!!  \n");
    return 1;
  }

  // << check if read data is equal to written data

  if (memcmp(data_to_read, data, n*dim) == 0)
  {
    printf("\nRead data is equal to written data\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: there may be other errors I didn't notice.

Comment: `printf("\nRead data is equal to written data\n");` -> `puts()` as you are not formatting anything. Also I don't get why you and a lot of other people declare `i` outside of the `for` loop and cast the return of `malloc`.  Better avoid doing these in C ?

Comment: @Badda just because I stuck to the OP's code, but yes I'll remove the casts. `puts` vs `printf`: putting `puts` is pointless because today's optimizing compilers usually take care of this and the gain is small anyway as the underlying I/O is slow compared to what you gain using `puts` instead of `printf`..

Answer (score 0):

I think I've spotted your problem:

You write this file:

```
FILE *fp=fopen("dataset.data", "w+");
```

But you read this file:

```
fp = fopen("Home/dataset.data", "rb");
```

You aren't reading the file you are writing.

Comment: No exactly, I fixed the path but still the same problem. Thanks for your checking though.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in this way:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("dataset.data", "wb+");
```

Then, after writing data with fwrite, close the file pointer or reset it:

```
fclose(fp);
//alternatively:
// fflush(fp); 
// fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Finally, correct the path of the second fopen