# Issue when reading file using fseek function

Tags: c

I am generating 500 random points (each point is of dimension=4) and writing them into a binary file as the following:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.bin", "wb+");
float *buf = (float *) calloc(500 * 4, sizeof(float));
srand(1);
for (i = 0; i < (500 * 4); ++i) {
    buf[i] = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX; // Later I shall treat every 4 values as one point.
}
fwrite(buf, sizeof(float), 500 * 4 * sizeof(float), fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Later in my code, I want to read only the first 100 points (i.e., 100*4 as each point is of dim=4). I use the following code to do so but I am having a problem and it does not really print anything:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb+");

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
int c, cnt=0;
while(1)
{
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if(feof(fp) || (cnt == 100)) { break; }
    printf("%c", c);
    cnt++;
}
printf("\n");
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: If you write with `fwrite()`, there's no text in the file — you need to use `fread()` to read the data.

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` `fp`before opening it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But `fread` does not allow to print the first 100 points! Right?

Comment: Why do you specify `sizeof(float)` twice in the fwrite? The third argument is the number of elements, which is 500 * 4, and you've already accounted for their individual size in argument 2.

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498779/issue-when-writing-and-reading-to-binary-file). It's not an exact duplicate, but you might get the answer to your question there.

Comment: Well, `fread()` doesn't print anything — so no, `fread()` won't allow you to print the first 100 points.  It will, however, allow you to read the first 100 points if used correctly.  The `fwrite()` call has `sizeof(float)` twice, which means you're writing 4 times as much data as you intended, but that's fixable and you'd still need to use `fread()` to read the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read back just 100 elements (as in 4 floats), that's the number you put into `fread` like so...

```
fread(buf, sizeof(float), 100 * 4, fp);
```

as per the various comments above your call to `fwrite` should look similar as you don't need the extra `sizeof(float)`

```
fwrite(buf, sizeof(float), 500 * 4, fp);
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you very much. I have a question. Instead of `fread` the first (100*4) points, what if I want to `fread` the points on a range, say starting from (100*4) to (200*4) (i.e., the points from 100 to 200), how would I modify this?

Comment: Then `fseek(fp, 100*4*sizeof(float), SEEK_SET);` and then `fread(buf,sizeof(float), 100*4)`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That's great. THANK YOU very much guys. Really appreciate it